# Spring Cacheable for getCollection and getById

Tags: spring, caffeine-cache

Im using the Cache-Abstraction of Spring with the CaffeineCache implementation.

In my JpaRepository are two methods:

```
Article findByArticleId(final Long articleId);
List<Article> findByArticleIdIn(Set<Long> articleIds);
```

To make them Cachable i would use:

```
@Cacheable(value = "article_cache", key = "#articleId")
Article findByArticleId(final Long articleId);

@Cacheable(value = "article_cache", key = "#articleIds")
List<Article> findByArticleIdIn(Set<Long> articleIds);
```

**Now my question:**
Is Spring "smart enough" to store only Article-Objects as cached values or would this result in two different types of keys and values?

If both methods are invoked for partially the same ids. Would the cache look like this (not good):

```
{
   "[1,2,3,4,5]": [Article@1, Article@2,..],
   "[2,3,4]": [Article@2, Article@3,..],
   "1": Article@1,
   "2": Article@2,
   ...
}
```

Or like this (wanted behavior):

```
{
   "1": Article@1,
   "2": Article@2,
   "3": Article@3,
   "4": Article@4,
   ...
}
```

The Article objects are quite large.
If the first behavior is true, how could I achieve the second one without implementing a custom cache?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will result in different keys and values. If you are using JPA don't use `@Cacheable` instead use 2nd level caching from your JPA provider instead. Caching the articels opens a whole can of worms when updating/deleting etc. all of which your JPA provider already thought of.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the fast comment! So should i use '@Cacheable' only if I need to cache objects that are not '@Entity" annotated? For my usecase with entities I will now look into Hibernate-L2 Caching

Comment: Or read-only reference data. But if you use this for objects that are going to be modified by the user you will have to take care of each place it can be modified and invalidate (all) caches that might hold it (either in a collection or single or even in a nested object for instance). This becomes a tedious and undoable task if your application grows.,